# Ranking of rows depends on the number of duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do this in MSSQL? I already search for rank built in functions but it didn't get this kind of ranking.

```
Term    Course_ID  Description   Grade   Rank
1601    001173     Gen Math       76      1 
1601    001235     21st Cent      79      1
1601    001235     21st Cent      73      2
1601    001247     Philosophy     81      1
1601    001247     Philosophy     71      2
1601    001259     Oral Com       76      1
1601    001548     English        85      1
```

I have to set the rank to 1 for the first record of that particular Course_Id and continue to count until the last duplicate and reset to 1 for another course_ID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: u should use ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Row_Number()` function instead of `Rank()` as below :

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Course_ID ORDER BY Course_ID) Rank
FROM <table_name>;
```

**Output :**

```
Term    Course_ID  Description   Grade   Rank
1601    001173     Gen Math       76      1 
1601    001235     21st Cent      79      1
1601    001235     21st Cent      73      2
1601    001247     Philosophy     81      1
1601    001247     Philosophy     71      2
1601    001259     Oral Com       76      1
1601    001548     English        85      1
```

Comment: Thanks @YogeshSharma I see that this is actually I need but I think I need to adjust my query because it returns all the rows in my database when I insert ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Ashiko if answer is useful then you vote or accept the solution which could help u.

Comment: The problem is on my condition why ROW_NUMBER() return a lots of records. It's now working. Thanks for your help. I used the ROW_NUMBER() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    Term        INT,
    Course_ID   VARCHAR(32),
    Description VARCHAR(100),
    Grade       INT
)

INSERT @Test
VALUES
    (1601,    '001173',     'Gen Math',       76),
    (1601,    '001235',     '21st Cent',      79),
    (1601,    '001235',     '21st Cent',      73),
    (1601,    '001247',     'Philosophy',     81),
    (1601,    '001247',     'Philosophy',     71),
    (1601,    '001259',     'Oral Com',       76),
    (1601,    '001548',     'English',        85)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Course_ID ORDER BY Term) [Rank], Term, Course_ID, Description, Grade
FROM @Test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solved with a `Rank` function `Partition By` the Course_ID. Please see my exampled [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ba22d/2)